# Vba my for loop deletes only half of rows

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, delete-row

i am doing a macro for a betting calculation. I have the following double for loop for deleting rows that match the if but it deletes only half of the rows that really matches

```
Sub calc()

    Dim db As String
    db = Worksheets("PRONO").Range("A1").Value

    Dim alldata As Workbook
    Dim i1 As Worksheet

    Set alldata = Workbooks(db)
    Set i1 = alldata.Worksheets("I1")



    For Each Match In Workbooks("BET EXCEL.xlsm").Worksheets("TEST").Range("A14:" & Range("A14").End(xlDown).Address)

        For Each Data In i1.Range("B2:" & i1.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address)

            If CDate(Data.Value) > CDate(Match.Value) Then
                MsgBox (Data.Row)
                i1.Rows(Data.Row).Delete

            End If

        Next




    Next


End Sub
```

Why?

I can't understand it

If someone can help me

Comment: Your inner loop needs to loop backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. When you delete, lets say, fifth row, all rows below go up. So, the row that was sixth is fifth now. But your loop goes to the recent sixth (former seventh), jumping over this one that used to be sixth. 
Use `FOR i = lastRow to 1 STEP -1` to delete rows upward. 
(ah, lastRow must be calculated before).

Comment: Ok, yes i think that's the solution, just I have to compare the 2 cells. How can i compare them inside the inner for ?

Comment: if the inner loop counter is iCount, you may refer to cell as il..Range("B" &iCount)

Comment: How I have to declare i and lastRow, with integer it gives me an error on type